# Combining AND OR statements in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, logical-operators

I would like to write a query that selects records by a number of different conditions and that uses operators AND and OR.

If I write the following query, for example, how do I keep the first two conditions (`network_id = 1 and payment_plan_id = 77`) without rewriting them after the `OR` statement?

```
select * from transactions where network_id = 1 and payment_plan_id = 
77 and payment_type = 'Subscription' OR payment_type = 'Renewal'
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you can just enclose the OR statement in parenthesis: `select * from transactions where network_id = 1 and payment_plan_id = 
77 and (payment_type = 'Subscription' OR payment_type = 'Renewal')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` to avoid the parenthesis confusion

```
select * from transactions 
where network_id = 1 
and payment_plan_id = 77 
and payment_type IN ('Subscription' , 'Renewal')
```

Answer (score 4):

Use parentheses:

```
select *
from transactions
where network_id = 1 and payment_plan_id = 77 and 
      (payment_type = 'Subscription' OR payment_type = 'Renewal')
```

Or, better yet, use `in`:

```
select *
from transactions
where network_id = 1 and payment_plan_id = 77 and 
      payment_type in ('Subscription', 'Renewal')
```